# Linux IFS environment variable is not used by gcc wordexp Posix C library function for splitting words

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix, ifs

#### Environment

OS: Ubunty 20.4, Centos 8, macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Language: C, C++
Compiler: gcc (most recent versions for each OS)

#### Issue

I am using *wordexp* Posix library function to get shell-like expansion of strings.
The expansion works fine with one exception: when I set $IFS environment variable to something other than whitespace, for example ':', it does not seem to affect splitting of the words that continues to be done on whitespace only regardless of the IFS value.

#### *bash* test

Man page for *wordexp* for Linux https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html states:

1. "The function wordexp() performs a shell-like expansion of the string..."
2. "Field splitting is done using the environment variable $IFS. If it is not set, the field separators are space, tab and newline."

This is why I expected *wordexp* to behave the same way as *bash* in this respect.
On all the listed OSes I got the same exactly correct and expected result when changing the character set used for splitting:
Using default (IFS is not set)

```
    read -a words <<<"1 2:3 4:5"
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do echo "$word";  done
```

correctly splits on space and produces the result:

```
    1
    2:3
    4:5
```

while setting IFS to ':'

```
    IFS=':' read -a words <<<"1 2:3 4:5"
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do echo "$word";  done
```

correctly splits on ':' and produces the result:

```
    1 2
    3 4
    5
```

#### C code test

But running the code below yields the same result regardless whether IFS environment variable is set or not:

C Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <wordexp.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    static void expand(char const *title, char const *str)
    {
        printf("%s input: %s\n", title, str);
        wordexp_t exp;
        int rcode = 0;
        if ((rcode = wordexp(str, &exp, WRDE_NOCMD)) == 0) {
            printf("output:\n");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < exp.we_wordc; i++)
                printf("%s\n", exp.we_wordv[i]);
            wordfree(&exp);
        } else {
            printf("expand failed %d\n", rcode);
        }
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        char const *str = "1 2:3 4:5";
        
        expand("No IFS", str);
    
        int rcode = setenv("IFS", ":", 1);
        if ( rcode != 0 ) {
            perror("setenv IFS failed: ");
            return 1;
        }
    
        expand("IFS=':'", str);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

The result in all OSes is the same:

```
    No IFS input: 1 2:3 4:5
    output:
    1
    2:3
    4:5
    IFS=':' input: 1 2:3 4:5
    output:
    1
    2:3
    4:5
```

As a note, the snippet above was created for this post - I did test with a more complex code that verified that the environment variable was indeed set properly.

#### Source code review

I looked at the source code for the *wordexp* function implementation available at https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/wordexp.c.html and it appears that it does use $IFS but perhaps inconsistently or maybe this is a bug.
Specifically:
In the body of *wordexp* that starts on **line 2229** it does get IFS environment variable value and processes it:
lines 2273 - 2276:

```
     /* Find out what the field separators are.
       * There are two types: whitespace and non-whitespace.
       */
      ifs = getenv ("IFS");
```

But then later on in the function it does not seem to
use the $IFS values for words separation.
This looks like a bug unless "field separators" on **line 2273**
and "word separator" on **line 2396** mean different things.
lines 2395 - 2398:

```
          default:
            /* Is it a word separator? */
            if (strchr (" \t", words[words_offset]) == NULL)
            {
```

But in any case the code seem to only use space or tab as a splitter
unlike *bash* that respects the IFS set splitter values.

#### Questions

1. Am I missing something and there is a way to get *wordexp* to split on characters other than whitespace?
2. If the split is only on whitespace, is this a bug in the

   - *gcc* library implementation or
   - in the Linux man page for *wordexp* where they claim that $IFS can be used to define splitters

**Many thanks in advance for all your comments and insights!**

#### Answers Summary and workaround

In the accepted answer there was a hint on how to achieve the split on non-whitespace characters from the $IFS: you have to set $IFS and put the string that you want to split as a value for a temporary environmental variable and then call *wordexp* against that temporary variable. This is demonstrated in the updated code below.
While this behavior that is visible in the source code may not be actually a bug it definitely looks like a questionable design decision to me…
Updated code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <wordexp.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    static void expand(char const *title, char const *str)
    {
        printf("%s input: %s\n", title, str);
        wordexp_t exp;
        int rcode = 0;
        if ((rcode = wordexp(str, &exp, WRDE_NOCMD)) == 0) {
            printf("output:\n");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < exp.we_wordc; i++)
                printf("%s\n", exp.we_wordv[i]);
            wordfree(&exp);
        } else {
            printf("expand failed %d\n", rcode);
        }
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        char const *str = "1 2:3 4:5";
        
        expand("No IFS", str);
    
        int rcode = setenv("IFS", ":", 1);
        if ( rcode != 0 ) {
            perror("setenv IFS failed: ");
            return 1;
        }
    
        expand("IFS=':'", str);
        
        rcode = setenv("FAKE", str, 1);
        if ( rcode != 0 ) {
            perror("setenv FAKE failed: ");
            return 2;
        }
    
        expand("FAKE", "${FAKE}");    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

which produces the result:

```
    No IFS input: 1 2:3 4:5
    output:
    1
    2:3
    4:5
    IFS=':' input: 1 2:3 4:5
    output:
    1
    2:3
    4:5
    FAKE input: ${FAKE}
    output:
    1 2
    3 4
    5
```

Comment: You could dive into the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of [MUSL libc](http://musl.libc.org/) to get the answer. You could try a different C library, e.g. [dietlibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietlibc). See also https://linuxfromscratch.org/; you could also try with a different C compiler, e.g. [CompCert](https://compcert.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)

Comment: The link that I posted for the source that I was looking at claims to be for glibc which is what GNU C Library is called. So I think that this is the actual code (maybe not the absolutely latest). Do you have a reason to think that it's not? In any case the behavior that I am observing matches that code quite well... Yes, I could try a different compiler but I am limited to gcc - it's a long story. But Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: You could recompile your libc (or your C code) with `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra`, and you could recompile [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) from its source code, and you could use [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) on either your C source code or the source code of your libc.

Comment: Of course, but troubleshooting libc is kind of out of scope for me. There were two reasons that I posted this question: a) in hope that I am wrong and there is a way to split on something other than whitespace, and b) to see where to put a bug report - on gcc lib or on linux man pages.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will take a look.

Comment: Use also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) - in addition of [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1gdb.1.html) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) - on your executable

Comment: By my read -- you are correct. This looks very much like a bug. I have added calls to `getenv ("IFS")` to confirm the environment sees the `setenv()` call -- and it does. Your usage is correct unless I'm missing something. Same behavior on `gcc (GCC) 10.2.0` and `gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.4.1`. (very nice write-up of the question)

Comment: I'm 99% sure you're confusing tokenization into words and splitting the results of expansions in those tokens in a later stage of parsing, but I'm not in a position to dig out the relevant references and whip up some examples. `wordexp()` does not do the same thing as the `read` built-in.

Comment: man bash IFS is "The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion "

Comment: @"David C. Rankin" Thank you very much for taking the time to look into this, and for the compliment :-)

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for looking into this. I may be not 100% sure on what difference (and why) would tokenization into words and  field separators be different but let me ask this: is it possible to use wordexp to achieve the behavior in my question i.e. split on something other than whitespace?

Comment: @stark Thank you for looking into this. Please see my comment to Shawn above - I couldn't put both of you on the comment.

Comment: wordexp only does shell command-line syntax, not general string-splitting.  Use strtok for that.

Comment: When you set `IFS=":"` and you type stuff on your terminal, you don't type `sh:-c:echo 1`  but type `sh -c 'echo 1'` separated by spaces and tabs anyway. IFS affects word splitting, not like field splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're  comparing apples to oranges. `wordexp()` splits a string up into individual tokens the same way the shell does. The shell builtin `read` doesn't follow the same algorithm; it just does word splitting. You should be comparing `wordexp()` to how the arguments to a script or shell function are parsed:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printwords() {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        printf "%s\n" "$arg"
    done
}

echo "No IFS input: 1 2:3 4:5"
printwords 1 2:3 4:5
echo "IFS=':' input: 1 2:3 4:5"
IFS=:
printwords 1 2:3 4:5
```

This produces

```
No IFS input: 1 2:3 4:5
1
2:3
4:5
IFS=':' input: 1 2:3 4:5
1
2:3
4:5
```

just like the C program.

---

Now, for the interesting bit. I couldn't find it explicitly mentioned as such in the POSIX documentation with a quick scan, but the [`bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) has this to say about word splitting:

> Note that if no expansion occurs, no splitting is performed.

Let's try a version that does parameter expansion in its arguments:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

printwords() {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        printf "%s\n" "$arg"
    done
}

foo=2:3
printf "foo = %s\n" "$foo"
printf "No IFS input: 1 \$foo 4:5\n"
printwords 1 $foo 4:5
printf "IFS=':' input: 1 \$foo 4:5\n"
IFS=:
printwords 1 $foo 4:5
```

which when run via shells like `dash`, `ksh93` or `bash` (But *not* `zsh` unless you turn on the `SH_WORD_SPLIT` option), produces

```
foo = 2:3
No IFS input: 1 $foo 4:5
1
2:3
4:5
IFS=':' input: 1 $foo 4:5
1
2
3
4:5
```

As you can see, the argument that has a parameter was subject to field splitting, but not the literal one. Making the same change to the string in your C program and running `foo=2:3 ./wordexp` prints out the same thing.

Comment: And of course `"$foo"` won't be subject to field splitting because of the quotes.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this. Maybe this is not a bug but is kind of a questionable design. This said, your answer suggested a workaround for my problem: if I want to split on $IFS I just need to set the string to an environment variable and then wordexp() the variable. This does yield the result that I was after. I will update the question with the workaround to be able to paste the code. Not sure if this is a good practice on SO...

Comment: @Leo If you just want to split up a string into an array based on a delimiter, `wordexp()` is massive overkill compared to something using `strtok_r()`.

Comment: I understand and totally agree. The reason I was looking into using workexp()  for splitting on non whitespace is to be able to properly split things like $PATH, for example, which potentially could contain other environment variables, ~, quoted strings, escaped delimiters, etc. Which won't be trivial with strtok_r() or similar. It does split typical $PATH with no special cases but I still need to check to see if that actually works properly with complicated case. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Let's naively assume POSIX is understandable and try to work with it. Let's take [wordexp() from posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html#):

> The words argument is a pointer to a string containing one or more words to be expanded. The expansions shall be the same as would be performed by the command line interpreter if words were the part of a command line representing the arguments to a utility. [...]

So let's go to "the command line interpreter". From [posix shell command language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):

> 2.1 Shell Introduction
>
> [...]
>
> 2. The shell breaks the input into tokens: words and operators; see Token Recognition.
>    [.......]
>
> 2.3 Token Recognition
>
> [...]
>
> 7. If the current character is an unquoted <blank>, any token containing the previous character is delimited and the current character shall be discarded.
> 8. If the previous character was part of a word, the current character shall be appended to that word.
>
> [...]

Basically the whole `2.3 Token Recognition` sections applies here - this is *the* thing that `wordexp()` does - token recognition plus some expansions. And also the most important stuff about [field splitting](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05), emphasis mine:

> After parameter expansion (Parameter Expansion), command substitution (Command Substitution), and arithmetic expansion (Arithmetic Expansion), the shell shall scan **the results of expansions and substitutions** that did not occur in double-quotes for field splitting and multiple fields can result.

`IFS` affects field splitting, it affects how the **result of other expansions** are spitted into words. `IFS` does not affect how string is split into tokens, it's still split using `<blank>` - tab or space. So the behavior you are seeing.

In other words, when you type `IFS=:` in your terminal, then you don't start separating tokens by `IFS`, like `echo:Hello:World`, but still continue separating parts of commands using spaces.

Anyway, the man page is correct... :p

> Am I missing something and there is a way to get wordexp to split on characters other than whitespace?

No. If you want to have spaces in words, quote the arguments, as you would in the shell. `"a b" "c d" "e"`.

> If the split is only on whitespace, is this a bug in the

None :p

Comment: Thanks you for your help with this. Your answer definitely clarified the situation for me and is much appreciated.  Unfortunately only one answer can be accepted and I had to accept the other answer because it provided the hint that allowed me to have a workaround. Thanks again, Leo.